# Flattening a very nested Spark Scala dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, nested, apache-spark-sql

I have a very nested dataframe that I'm trying to flatten. The original schema looks like:

```
 |-- _History: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Article: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- Id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- Timestamp: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Channel: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Music: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- Sports: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- Style: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
```

I'm able to flatten most fields using the recursive function:

```
implicit class DataFrameFlattener(df: DataFrame) {
  def flattenSchema: DataFrame = {
    df.select(flatten(Nil, df.schema): _*)
  }

  protected def flatten(path: Seq[String], schema: DataType): Seq[Column] = schema match {
    case s: StructType => s.fields.flatMap(f => flatten(path :+ f.name, f.dataType))
    case other => col(path.map(n => s"`$n`").mkString(".")).as(path.mkString(".")) :: Nil
  } 
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to be able to flatten `_History.Article.Id` and `_History.Article.Timstamp` in the schema above. Why is this and how do I flatten these two fields into their own columns within the dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

Using scala spark you can flatten the json recursively:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{ Row, SaveMode, SparkSession, DataFrame }
def recurs(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
  if(df.schema.fields.find(_.dataType match {
    case ArrayType(StructType(_),_) | StructType(_) => true
    case _ => false
  }).isEmpty) df
  else {
    val columns = df.schema.fields.map(f => f.dataType match {
      case _: ArrayType => explode(col(f.name)).as(f.name)
      case s: StructType => col(s"${f.name}.*")
      case _ => col(f.name)
    })
    recurs(df.select(columns:_*))
  }
}
val df = spark.read.json(json_location)
flatten_df = recurs(df)
flatten_df.show()
```

This will create the array in perticular column.

#

If you don't want the array and append in another row there is another one:

```
def flattenDataframe(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    //getting all the fields from schema
    val fields = df.schema.fields
    val fieldNames = fields.map(x => x.name)
    //length shows the number of fields inside dataframe
    val length = fields.length
    for (i <- 0 to fields.length - 1) {
      val field = fields(i)
      val fieldtype = field.dataType
      val fieldName = field.name
      fieldtype match {
        case arrayType: ArrayType =>
          val fieldName1 = fieldName
          val fieldNamesExcludingArray = fieldNames.filter(_ != fieldName1)
          val fieldNamesAndExplode = fieldNamesExcludingArray ++ Array(s"explode_outer($fieldName1) as $fieldName1")
          //val fieldNamesToSelect = (fieldNamesExcludingArray ++ Array(s"$fieldName1.*"))
          val explodedDf = df.selectExpr(fieldNamesAndExplode: _*)
          return flattenDataframe(explodedDf)

        case structType: StructType =>
          val childFieldnames = structType.fieldNames.map(childname => fieldName + "." + childname)
          val newfieldNames = fieldNames.filter(_ != fieldName) ++ childFieldnames
          val renamedcols = newfieldNames.map(x => (col(x.toString()).as(x.toString().replace(".", "_").replace("$", "_").replace("__", "_").replace(" ", "").replace("-", ""))))
          val explodedf = df.select(renamedcols: _*)
          return flattenDataframe(explodedf)
        case _ =>
      }
    }
    df
  }
```

Just call this like the previous one, import some libraries if I missed.

Comment: Thanks Bro !!! second worked for me. I searched a lot for nested and found this !
Note : whoever uses this code, sometimes, spark gives exceptions that it is not able to find the column though column is there because the column name is like a.b.name or a.b.rank. 
Be sure to rename the column names before performing operations on it. like a.b.name to name and a.b.rank to rank
giving up wote as a duty.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around: create two new columns of the flattened fields:

```
val flatDF = df
    .withColumn("_History.Article.Id", df("`_History.Article`.Id")
    .withColumn("_History.Article.Timestamp", df("`_History.Article`.Timestamp")
```